# IPN Listener is not returning Variables in response: Sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a working application that makes payments via adaptive chained payments. This works fine, however I'm now implementing an IPN Listener to handle refunds. I'm testing in the sandbox.

I've confirmed that when a refund is made in PayPal directly the IPN Listener gets a refund message however I don't see any of the Variables that the document talks about regarding refund amounts.

The response I see is in the post data is:

```
11/Mar/2015:09:33:01] (ipn_handler) [-1-] : POST
array (
 'transaction' =>
array (
0 => 'NONE',
1 => 'Refunded',
 ),
  'log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction' => 'false',
   'action_type' => 'PAY',
  'ipn_notification_url' => 'http://example.com/paypal/ipn_handler.php',
  'charset' => 'windows-1252',
'transaction_type' => 'Adjustment',
'notify_version' => 'UNVERSIONED',
'reason_code' => 'Refund',
'cancel_url' => 'http://example.com/paymentCancel.php',
'verify_sign' =>   'AFcWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwy5O5OqOKKa.xxxx',
'sender_email' => 'zakbuyer@gmail.com',
'fees_payer' => 'EACHRECEIVER',
'return_url' => 'http://example.com/paymentSuccess.php',
'memo' => 'purchase of item Gear Shift cufflink',
'reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error' => 'false',
'pay_key' => 'AP-5KHxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'status' => 'COMPLETED',
'test_ipn' => '1',
'payment_request_date' => 'Thu Mar 05 01:09:00 PST 2015',
)
```

I was expecting to find mc_gross and mc_currency etc.
With the data provided I can look up the transaction no problem but I can't handle if a partial refund is done.

I'm finding my information at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

Answer (score 0):

When working with Adaptive Payments there are actually two separate IPN listeners that need to be acknowledged.

The value that you're setting in the IPNNotificationURL parameter of your Adaptive Payments API requests is an application specific IPN.  The data sent to that listener is data that an application owner might want to help track transactions that are getting run through their app, but this data is very limited in terms of actual transaction details.

To get the parameters you're expecting, IPN would need to be configured in the seller account (in this case, the refunder's account).  Then when the refund takes place PayPal would send an IPN to that listener with the parameters you're expecting to see.

Comment: Thanks for that Andrew. So in effect there's no way the applications IPN handler can find out the amount of a refund that has taken place. This is disappointing as the application I'm running is an ecommerce site. I use the money passing through the system to provide reports so lacking the refund amount I won't be able to calculate this properly. At least I'm aware of this now. Do you have a link that highlights this issue?